# Read Javascript date input in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a calendar/datepicker done in Javascript that creates an input of the following format "Thu Mar 29 2018"

On submit, I want to read the date in a Django date field, but it fails.

What solutions do I have ?

Comment: How does it fail? Does it not like the format you are sending? Do you have a traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

In your case

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_format = "%a %b %d %Y"
date_object = datetime.strptime("Thu Mar 29 2018", datetime_format)
```